# parse XML Subfolders in to iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, ipad

XML file:
i can not parse the subfolder of XML shown below

[image]

i am able to parse the content of xml file by using method:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentelement=[elementName copy];
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Content"] ) {
        item=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


    }
}
```

but i cannot parse the sub folder `"PictureURL"`, i am getting null if i parse this in

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
        if ([currentelement isEqualToString:@"PictureURL"])
        {                   
           [item setObject:string forKey:@"Info8"];
        }
}
```

can any one let me know hoe to access the sub folder of the XML. thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426690/getting-attributes-of-child-and-subchild-using-nsxmlparser

Comment: its similar but i cannot access it..still

Comment: When you say you are getting null, what do you mean. Where are you trying to find its value. Did you put a break point or NSLog right after [item setObject:...]

Comment: What 'subfolder' are you talking about? Do you want to place this XML file into the app bundle, or what?